# How to allow scrolling toolbar with a non-tabbed viewPager that contains a horizontal scrollView?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have an activity with a custom toolbar and a non tabbed ViewPager. My aim to allow the toolbar to scroll/hide when i scroll the fragment in the viewPager horizontally so I added `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`
in the Toolbar. This however only hides the toolbar when i pan the toolbar and not when scrolling the viewPager. So I thought maybe the Toolbar is not picking the scroll event from the ViewPager so i wrapped the viewPager in a `NestedScrollView`. This works but it now does not allow me to scroll the entire length of my viewPager. Any pointers anyone?

**Note:** The fragment views in my viewPager each contain a scrollView that allows horizontal scrolling

```html
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/main_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/view_case_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
  
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given a little amount of details about your views. But I will give it a try.

First of all, everything should be inside `CoordinatorLayout`. It should have the parameter `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`. `AppBarLayout` also should have `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`. `Toolbar` should have `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to hide and show. And scrolling view should have `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` parameter.

It should look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I have it except for `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` which I have just amended, but the Toolbar is still not hiding in this configuration. (Only hides when i swipe the toolbar and not the view pager)

Comment: "My aim to allow the toolbar to scroll/hide when i scroll the fragment in the viewPager horizontally" - this just won't work. My solution will work while scrolling the content of `ViewPager` vertically. You have to implement your own `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` and assign it to `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewApp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:background="@drawable/sunshine22"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The attributes are self-explanatory. For details, you can refer R.Zagorski answer.

Comment: Sorry im not implementing a CollapsingToolbarLayout (Nor tablayout) in my views